# Increased data usage on a VPN connection

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, internet-connection, compression

I have been working on a remote computer over a VPN connection using Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection. I RDP from my laptop (with non-HD display). Recently my wife has also been working from home for her company using a similar setup as mine. She connects from a desktop (with full HD monitor). We have separate internet connections on both computers.

However, we have been seeing a sudden surge in data usage on desktop internet connection where my wife works. Our work is pretty similar. Yet some days her data download reaches 1 GB mark while mine is about 100-200 MB.

Since we don't have a connection with unlimited data plan we need to worry about this sudden increase in usage. One factor can be that she is using a full HD monitor thus making heavier desktop image transfer over RDP.

Apart from that is there anything our RDP connections are doing differently? Mine applying some compression while hers is not? If so, are there any settings that we can change on our end? Or is it something sys admins of our respective employers only can take care of?